# Pasting first row behind every column in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a tab-delimited file as such (but with way more columns)

```
1       2          3        4        5       6 
gene1   gene39   gene339   gene2     gene1   gene2
gene3   gene9    gene23    gene5     gene11  gene3
gene23  gene9    gene8     gene1     gene7   gene8
```

I want to take each column 1, and paste it alongside that column.  It would look something like this

```
gene1  1   gene39  2   gene339  3   gene2  4   gene1   5  gene2  6
gene3  1   gene9   2   gene23   3   gene5  4   gene11  5  gene3  6
gene23 1   gene9   2   gene8    3   gene1  4   gene7   5  gene8  6
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: And make sure the title says what you mean.  You say **in front of every column**, but your sample output has it **behind every column**.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s%s%s", $i, OFS, i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) }' file
gene1   1       gene39  2       gene339 3       gene2   4       gene1   5       gene2   6
gene3   1       gene9   2       gene23  3       gene5   4       gene11  5       gene3   6
gene23  1       gene9   2       gene8   3       gene1   4       gene7   5       gene8   6
```

Comment: I didn't bother trying to get the columns nicely aligned as I presumed it wouldn't make any differences when text-processing this. I can see that you and @tink have done that so it must be important. Why though?

Comment: The OP said he had tab-delimited input so I just gave him tab-delimited output. I assume he has his reasons - maybe he has some other tool he uses on it that expects tab-delimited fields or maybe he just thinks it looks pretty or MAYBE his real data can have blank chars within fields, idk.

Comment: @customcommander so to be clear, I didn't care about the alignment (if I did I'd just pipe the output to `column`), but I did care about the separator and that just coincidentally with the given sample  input produces visually aligned output.

Comment: Yeah I can see that in your BEGIN clause; clever :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are numbered sequentially, would this work?

```
NR > 1 {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    printf "%s %d ", $i, i
  }
  print
}
```

Comment: The only real problem with that is it'll add a blank to the end of every line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){ printf "%s\t%s\t", $i,i};printf "%s\t%s\n", $NF,NF}' steveman
gene1   1       gene39  2       gene339 3       gene2   4       gene1   5       gene2   6
gene3   1       gene9   2       gene23  3       gene5   4       gene11  5       gene3   6
gene23  1       gene9   2       gene8   3       gene1   4       gene7   5       gene8   6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl,

```
$ cat steveman.txt
1       2          3        4        5       6
gene1   gene39   gene339   gene2     gene1   gene2
gene3   gene9    gene23    gene5     gene11  gene3
gene23  gene9    gene8     gene1     gene7   gene8
$ perl -F"/\s+/" -lane ' @FH=@F if $.==1; if($.>1) { for($i=0;$i<@F;$i++) { printf("%s\t%s\t",$F[$i],$FH[$i]) } print "" } ' steveman.txt
gene1   1       gene39  2       gene339 3       gene2   4       gene1   5       gene2   6
gene3   1       gene9   2       gene23  3       gene5   4       gene11  5       gene3   6
gene23  1       gene9   2       gene8   3       gene1   4       gene7   5       gene8   6
$
```